# Batch FTP Folder uploading

Tags: batch, ftp

Hey I am trying to upload a entire folder to a webpage and I use this batch-file code:

```
;@echo off
;(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%~f0") do call
echo.%%A)>"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"
;ftp -i -s:"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"
;goto:EOF

open example.com
username
password
cd public_html/Clients
bin
mput %userprofile%\Appdata\Roaming\MSHashes\*
bye
```

But it doesn't upload the folder in `%Appdata%\MSHashes`.
What do I need to do to upload a entire folder to FTP?
Please answer, because I need this.

Comment: Then why did you comment out most of your batch file?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: On SO I voted to close this duplicate there and leave it here. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: thank you for taking it down because I didnt know how I take it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a sample of some syntax you can use as a template to build the FTP commands with and then execute the script afterwards.

> **You just need to**
>
> 1. create the directory on the FTP server first with the `mkdir` command.
> 2. optionally change the client root directory with the `lcd` command
> 3. upload the files to the newly created folder you made with `mput` or `put` commands

### Batch Script Example

```
SET ftptmpfile=%temp%\~tmpFTPprocess123.tmp
IF EXIST "%ftptmpfile%" DEL /Q /F "%ftptmpfile%"

:FTPScriptBuild
(
ECHO open example.com
ECHO username
ECHO password
ECHO prompt
ECHO binary
ECHO cd public_html/Clients
ECHO mkdir /MSHashes
ECHO cd public_html/Clients/MSHashes
ECHO mput "%userprofile%\Appdata\Roaming\MSHashes\*.*"
ECHO dir
ECHO bye
)>>"%ftptmpfile%"
```

### Raw FTP Commands

```
open example.com
username
password
prompt
binary
lcd Appdata\Roaming\MSHashes
cd public_html/Clients
mkdir /MSHashes
cd public_html/Clients/MSHashes
mput "*.*"
dir
bye
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FTP](https://ss64.com/nt/ftp.html)

  > ```
  > mkdir directory
  >              Create a directory on the remote host.
  >
  > lcd [directory]
  >              Change the working directory on the local PC.
  >              By default, the working directory is the directory in which ftp was started.
  >
  > put local-file [remote-file]
  >              Copy a local file to the remote host.
  >
  > mput local-files [ ...]
  >              Copy multiple local files to the remote host.
  > ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55600/discussion-on-answer-by-magicallydelicous-batch-ftp-folder-uploading).